# Sending a file to a server using sockets in Python

Tags: python, sockets

Mainpage displays my front page and upload is supposed to display the page
where you enter the file you wish to store with the server

```
def upload():
        path_name = raw_input("Enter your file directory")
        open_file = open(path_name,'rb').read()
        name_split = path_name.split("\\")[-1].split('.')
        at = 1

        s.send("SAVE-"+username+"\\"+"".join(name_split[:-1])+"."+str(at)+"."+name_split[-1]+"-")

        while open_file:
            current = open_file[:1024]
            print current
            open_file = open_file[1024:]
            s.send(current)


def mainpage():
        global R2
        R2=Tk()
        gg="white"
        g="blue"
        R2.geometry('720x720')
        R2.title(username + " Dropbox")
        R2.resizable(width=False,height=False)
        logoutbt= Button(R2,text="Logout",width=10,height=2,bg=g,fg=gg,font="5",relief=RAISED,overrelief=RIDGE,command=deslogout)
        upload = Button(R2,text="Upload",width=10,height=2,bg=g,fg=gg,font="5",relief=RAISED,overrelief=RIDGE,command=desupload)
        retrieve = Button(R2,text="Retreive",width=10,height=2,bg=g,fg=gg,font="5",relief=RAISED,overrelief=RIDGE,command=desretreive)
        logoutbt.place(x = 220,y = 500)
        retrieve.place(x = 350,y = 500)
        upload.place(x = 480,y = 500)
        R2.mainloop()    
        open(path_name,'rb').close()
```

Now when I add the command mainpage() to return back to to my main page after sending the file to the server,the server gets stuck in an infinite loop

```
ServerCode

if message[0] == "SAVE":
                    if not os.path.exists("C:\Heights\Documents\Projects\HomeWork\Project\Server1\\Files\\"+message[1].split("\\")[0]):
                        os.makedirs("C:\Heights\Documents\Projects\HomeWork\Project\Server1\\Files\\"+message[1].split("\\")[0])
                    file =open("C:\Heights\Documents\Projects\HomeWork\Project\Server1\\Files\\"+ message[1],"wb")
                    content = ""
                    while True:
                        data = current_socket.recv(1024)
                        if not data:
                            break
                        content += data

                    file.write(content)
                    file.close()
```

The file reaches the server fine when I don't try to return, but the moment I add that one extra line, the server doesn't exit its loop where it receives all the file content. Also,if I try to get a response from the server when it's done writing all the data down, the client and the server get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's `socket.recv(...)` inherits semantics from Unix `recv(2)` function, and as stated in `recv(2)` man:

> If no messages are available at the socket, the receive calls wait  for a  message  to arrive, unless the socket is nonblocking

Therefore, since `current_socket` is blocking, your server just hangs on the line `data = current_socket.recv(1024)` infinitely right after the whole file has been read to the `content` variable until the socket on the client becomes properly closed.

To avoid that:

- **On the client side** send your file size in bytes before sending any of its contents:

  ```
  import struct

  ...

  file_len_bytes = pack('!i', len(open_file))
  s.send(file_len_bytes)

  while open_file:
      ....
  ```
- **On the server side** read your file size and then use it to check whether the whole file has been read:

  ```
  import struct

  ...

  file_len_bytes = ""
  while len(file_len_bytes) < 4:
      file_len_bytes += client.recv(1)
  file_len = struct.unpack("!i", file_len_bytes[:4])[0]

  content = ""
  bytes_read = 0
  while bytes_read < file_len:
      data = current_socket.recv(1024)
      bytes_read += len(data)
      content += data
  ```

Comment: Great! I'm really happy to be helpful, and I would highly appreciate if you mark my answer as an accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, As a general rule, waiting for the socket to return nothing(empty string or whatever), is a bad idea. That is because **in python a socket would only return empty data if the other side closed his socket.** But if there was a problem or for any reason the socket was not closed properly, the socket.recv method would hang perhaps infinitely.

Secondly, I see that you intend to instantiate your TKinter App more than once. 
This is bad practice, and you should consider just hiding your main window.

Hope I was helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.